# mongoose use findOneAndUpdate and only return the updated element in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have following problem:

```
  let post = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: USER_ID },
    {
      $push: {
        posts: {
          title,
          content,
          userId: USER_ID,
          titleUrl,
          thumbnail: {
            webp: WEBP_PATH,
            jpeg: JPEG_PATH,
            placeholder: PLACEHOLDER
          }
        }
      }
    },
    { new: true }
  );
```

This query almost works well. The problem is whenever i push an item to the array i want to get the updated element back. Unfortunetally i get the whole document with all the posts in the array. Sure i could do something like `posts.slice(-1)` but i think this is super inefficient to load everything if i just need 1 element isnt it?

Somebody has an idea how to get just the new added object?

Comment: Were you able to try the answer? Could you approve if it was helpful or post an answer which would be helpful for others or clarify?

Comment: @Gibbs couldnt find. would maybe work with a aggregation framework but for the begin its fine. i slice it out with `posts.slice(-1)`

Comment: I don't think there is support till 4.2. I ll check 4.4 and update the answer if support is there

Comment: @Gibbs thats nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no option with `findOneAndUpdate`

You can do `projection` on original document but not on the updated document with `findOneAndUpdate`

I don't think there is no easy efficient way to do this.